# Find Div in DataList in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datalist

I have a div in asp:DataList, which includes some other divs. I tried to find the divs by `document.getElementByID("")`.

it called: `Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference.`

As a result I understood that the `.getElementById` can't find it.
Then how can I get them?
I tried to find my datalist by old posts but none of them match to my problem.

Note: My `divs` should be dragged, and they do, but I can't get the value of their positions because of this problem.

Code:

```
function FullDragging() {
   // some code
   var dd = document.getElementById("DesigningDiv"); // frame
   var logoObject = document.getElementById("logoObject"); // draggable element
   var nameObject = document.getElementById("nameObject"); // draggable element

   function getDesigningDivSize() {
            var dd = document.getElementById("DesigningDiv");
            var aspDesigningDivHF = document.getElementById('<%=aspDesigningDivHF.ClientID %>'); // hidden-field which sends the changes in client-side to the server.
            aspDesigningDivHF.value = parseInt(dd.style.width) + "," + parseInt(dd.style.height);
        }
}
window.onload = FullDragging;
```

because the function is called onload, the error appears onload also.

HTML:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ProductID" Height="400px" Width="1400px" OnEditCommand="DataList1_EditCommand" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" CellPadding="40" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnCancelCommand="DataList1_CancelCommand" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" OnUpdateCommand="DataList1_UpdateCommand">
 <ItemTemplate> ... </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
  <div id="DesigningDiv" style="height: 150px; width: 262.5px; border-style: groove; border-color: inherit; border-width: 1px; position: relative; height: 158px; width: 270px; background-color: #FFFFFF; visibility: hidden">
  <div id="logoObject" style="width: 51px; top: 31px; position: absolute; height: 34px; font-family: 'times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: bold; color: #333333; cursor: move; left: 187px;"> logo </div>              
  <div id="nameObject" style="width: 61px; top: 31px; position: absolute; height: 22px; font-family: 'times New Roman', Times, serif; color: #666666; font-size: large; cursor: move; font-weight: bold; left: 29px; bottom: 105px;"> full name </div>
 </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Please add your code that demonstrates the error.

Comment: What's your relevant html? And JavaScript? Maybe we can help, if we can see your problem.

Comment: editted.. I hope it is clear enough. If not, tell me what and I will do my best to explain in depth.

Comment: hey. good news - I fixed it. I changed the event so that my function FullDragging will be called when the edit button will be clicked. But strangely, it calls it again when I click on the update button. I guess so because this message: "the Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference" appears again. What should I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

a few problems, you shouldn't be populating an item template with static IDs as an ID should only appear once in an html document.

Consider applying a class to these divs and referencing them that way.

Once your page is rendered, right click and inspect one of these elements. ASP may be adding an extra prefix to your IDs as it is part of a datalist (e.g. DivLabel1 in visual studio becomes DataList1_DivLabel1 once the page is loaded) javascript isn't in on this conversion so you are better off referring to these items by class